# Assembly Microsoft.Office.Word.Server in sharepoint 2013 not found in SharePoint 2013 gac

Tags: sharepoint-server, word-automation

I was trying to create solution to convert document to pdf using Word Automation service. But for that need to add assembly Microsoft.Office.Word.Server as a reference in project.

When i try to do that, no such assembly exist in my gac!

What's wrong in that?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, this assembly is present in ISAPI folder under 14/15 hive.